# code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' WITH TypeORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am having a issue using typeORM to a CRUD application. I get this error when i try to connect the server to the database (MySQL). The credencials are correct, but I still have error. I am using ormconfig.json

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:863:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:860:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:288:51)
    at step (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/ivan/Programming/TypeORM_CRUD/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
}
```

The ormconfig.json file are:

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "database_app",
    "entities": ["dist/entity/**/*.js"],
    "synchronize": true
 }
```

Comment: you apparently not using the correct credentials

Comment: @DanielA.White I am. I used the same credentials in mysql cli and I have not problems.